# Is there documentation available for jquery.couch.app.js?

Tags: jquery, couchapp

Does anyone know if there is documentation available for:

> jquery.couch.app.js

I see it getting used in plenty of couchapps that I have the source for but as I read through them trying to figure out what is & isn't available to the callback methods passed into stuff like $.couch.app(function callback(){}) it becomes bit of a hit & miss without docs.

So far all I found is:

> http://couchapp.couchone.com/docs/_design/docs/index.html#/topic/couchapp

And that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jquery.couch.app.js`](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/blob/master/couchapp/templates/vendor/_attachments/jquery.couch.app.js) it's only e thin wrapper around [`jquery.couch.js`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/www/script/jquery.couch.js). More specifically it wraps [`$.couch.db`](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.db.html), somewhat documented at [jquery.couch.js-docs](https://github.com/daleharvey/jquery.couch.js-docs).

However my suggestion is to study the source. It's small, simple, and (by definition) accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the sound advice. But code is code and documentation is documentation. Having a great utility without telling what each method does is a lack of documentation. I have posted this question in an attempt to get the community's help because either the author or another expert-user may have taken a step forward to document the intent behind each util funtion and what it provides.

Comment: @pulkitsinghal Read more carefully at the links I've posted. http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/index.html looks like documentation to me. Anyway the problem is that CouchDB tools are still young and any documentation you will find will be outdated in a short period of time. That's why I suggest to read the source when this source is small and readable.

Comment: Yup already had that link before the post but I do appreciate you pointing it out. Once again I understand that to some folks jquery.couch.app.js is a thin wrapper around jquery.couch.js but what I'm asking for is if there is docs on that thin wrapper :)

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is any other way around it. The best I could find was more docs around jquery.couch.js (https://github.com/lenalena/couchdb-http-api-docs) which are also half-complete like the ones recommended earlier (http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/index.html). I call both of htem incomplete because they both talk about "options" as a parameter but both don't cover what those options are ... well they do but its a 50/50 chance that they will have a relevant link or not. I hope that between the two of them I can get what I need.

Comment: Also this should be somewhat helpful: http://www.couchbase.org/sites/default/files/uploads/all/documentation/couchbase-api.html for a mad search as at the end of the day the options are those supported by CouchDB itself.